# How to Convert an NSstring to NSerror object type

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to Convert an NSstring to NSerror object type .

For Example

```
NSString *msg;
msg  = "ERROR - Error Domain=Handling Login Response Code=20017 "Invalid user name" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid user name} errorCode 20017 . "
```

I want to convert the nsstring[msg] into NSerror Type, because I want to print  "Invalid user name" using `error.localizedDescription`

Comment: You can't really unmake the sausage.  It looks like you already had an NSError somewhere but you now have the string value.  Or do you want to create an `NSError` object? In which case you would need to [create one](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nserror?language=objc)

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11. Do not use `-description` to recreate something. That's bad behavior. Apple could change it, for your custom objects, you may also change it. It's bad habit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use NSError in my iPhone App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654653/how-can-i-use-nserror-in-my-iphone-app)

Answer (score 3):

I believes you want to create your own `NSError` object.

```
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.yourcompany.appname" code:3456 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Invalid user name."}];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
```