# How to convert an exception into an NSError object

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, react-native-ios

I want to convert the message of an exception into an NSError object so that I can use it within a try-catch block (I'm actually working on a [native iOS module for React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)).

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(myMethod:(NSDictionary *)dict
             resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
             rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  @try {
    // Do something which could throw something (NS Error or NS Exception)
    resolve(nil);
  } @catch (NSException *exception) {
    // HERE I WANT TO TRANSFORM THE EXCEPTION exception INTO AN ERROR error
    NSError error = ???
    reject(@"my_error", @"Could not do something important", error);
  }
}
```

I want to convert the exception into an `NSError` because the third parameter of the `reject` function (which rejects a Promise on the JS side) expects the input to be of type `NSError`. I'm not sure whether my solution (using try-catch) is the best thing in this scenario..

In [this Apple Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html) it says

> You can convert an exception into an NSError object and then present the information in the error object to the user in an alert panel.

However the guide does not show a code sample for that and only shows a code sample for a second approach *You can also return them indirectly in methods that include an error parameter* which seems to complicated for what I want.

So, how would I convert an exception into an NSError? [The API reference of NSError](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nserror) does not seem to contain a suitable function..

Comment: How do you wish to make use of the `NSError`? Do you really need an `NSError`?

Comment: @rmaddy I edited my code snippet to better reflect my use case and explained why I want to use `NSError` and can't use `NSException`. Or could I?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use NSError in my iPhone App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654653/how-can-i-use-nserror-in-my-iphone-app)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't convert `NSException` to `NSError` because `NSException` they do not have the same properties. Is there any reason for catching `NSException` instead of building a `**NSError` mechanism? Exceptions are usually fatal and non-recoverable while Errors are non-fatal and recoverable.

If you need to go through with converting an `NSException` to an `NSError` anyway, you can do it manually like so:

```
@try {
    // Something
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSMutableDictionary * info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [info setValue:exception.name forKey:@"ExceptionName"];
    [info setValue:exception.reason forKey:@"ExceptionReason"];
    [info setValue:exception.callStackReturnAddresses forKey:@"ExceptionCallStackReturnAddresses"];
    [info setValue:exception.callStackSymbols forKey:@"ExceptionCallStackSymbols"];
    [info setValue:exception.userInfo forKey:@"ExceptionUserInfo"];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:yourdomain code:errorcode userInfo:info];
    //use error
}
```

Comment: The reason for catching `NSException` is that is what is being thrown.

Comment: Sorry, coming from Swift I forgot only `NSExceptions` can be caught in Obj-C. I've updated my answer. It should provide you with the stuff you need to convert your exception to an error.

Comment: @Oskar you can catch both `NSError` and `NSException`. Either with one `@catch(id e)` clause or one clause for each (`@try { ... } @catch(NSError err) { ... } @catch(NSException ex) { ... }`)

Comment: @kevin what oskar was trying to say was that if an `NSException *` is being thrown, you can't catch it with an `NSError *`  clause

Comment: This can be written a little more elegantly, and also needs some validation to prevent crashes - attempting to [info setValue:xxx for key:yyy] where xxx is nil (any of the exception fields used here) will crash immediately.

Answer (score 2):

`NSError` is a very flexible class that allows a very extensible error reporting system, thus nobody forbids you to do this:

```
/// NSExcetion * e = ...;
[NSError errorWithDomain:e.name code:0 userInfo:@{
    NSUnderlyingErrorKey: e,
    NSDebugDescriptionErrorKey: e.userInfo ?: @{ },
    NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: (e.reason ?: @"???") }];
}
```

The header files say about `NSUnderlyingErrorKey`:

> The value of this key should be an NSError.

But *should* is not *must* and code that blindly relies that something found in a dictionary has a specific class is broken to begin with. Also that's the just the header; the official developer documentation of that key says no such thing and this documentation is authoritative.

And for those who wunder what `e.userInfo ?: @{ }` and `e.reason ?: @"???"` means, it's just a shorter way of writing:

```
e.reason != nil ? e.reason : @"???"
```

In the end, code may recognize certain errors and handle them in a specific way but all code must be written to accept any error, even unknown ones and offer some kind of default handling for that case. If it is your code, you know that the error domain may be an exception name, so you can check for that and third party code will just treat that as an unknown error.

Comment: Should `NSDebugDescriptionErrorKey: e.userInfo` rather not be `NSDebugDescriptionErrorKey: e.description` ?

Comment: @LeslieGodwin `-desrciption` is a method of `NSObject` and just means "Give me a printable string that describes this object" which can be pretty much anything. Yet the userInfo of an exception can contain plenty of useful information about how, why and where this exception took place but the format is exception specific. The value of `NSDebugDescriptionErrorKey` is printed in various debug places as `%@`, which calls `-description` on its value and gives you a nice human readable printout of the userInfo dictionary of the exception.

Comment: I think it a poor choice to translate exception name into error-domain - these are not compatible, and I'd say the programmer should provide concrete error domain for their app or library, or even workflow. In addition, I'd use as much data from the NSException to enrich the userInfo with whatever I know about the exception - using custom keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do in my code. My design decision was not to "convert" the exception into an NSError, and so lose much of the information in it, but rather to create my own NSError object representing the notion that "an exception has occurred" and EMBED data from the NSException into that NSError, like thus:

```
    NSError *err = nil;
    @try {
        //! ... Lot's of work done here...
    } 
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSMutableDictionary *info = [exception.userInfo mutableCopy]?:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [info addEntriesFromDictionary: [exception dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"ExceptionName", @"ExceptionReason", @"ExceptionCallStackReturnAddresses", @"ExceptionCallStackSymbols"];
        [info addEntriesFromDictionary:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: exception.name, NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey:exception.reason }];
        err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"myErrorDomain" code:-10 userInfo:info];
    } 
    @finally {
        //! --- wrap up and return --- 
    }
```

This will preserve most of the exception information, while having a concrete, identifiable NSError to hand to caller.