# how to return different type of data from method in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c. I have an mainViewController class and i created another object class. I am declaring the other class inside the .h file of the mainViewController. I use

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "OtherClass.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) OtherClass *jsonData;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Then i call a function of the Other Class from the mainViewController .m file.

The method returns NSMutableArray and it works. But there is a possibility an error might occur so it might not return the NSMutableArray but an NSError. I need the class to return the error to the mainViewController.

How can i achieve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: How you are sending data from your otherclass to mainViewcontroller class via delegate or NsNotificationcenter?

Comment: I just use return data in the other class method. I dont know another method to send them back to the viewcontroller, this is what i am looking for...

Comment: In oldschool Apple API a so called `NSError**` out argument is passed https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506866-save?language=objc . Actual example https://stackoverflow.com/a/4654759/5329717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `id jsonData` instead of `OtherClass *jsonData`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) OtherClass *jsonData;
```

=>

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id jsonData;
```

And then do

```
if ([jsonData isKindOfClass: [OtherClass class]]) 
{

} 
else if ([jsonData isKindOfClass: [NSError class]]) 
{
} 
else 
{
    //It's none
}
```

But maybe you want to have 2 properties, might be simpler to use with just `if (jsonData) {}` or `if (jsonError) {}`?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) OtherClass *jsonData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSError *jsonError;
```

Another possibility would be to embed that into a custom object:

```
@interface ResponseData: NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) OtherClass *data;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSError *error;
@end
```

And then:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) ResponseData *json;
@end
```

And check `json.data` or `json.error`?

Answer (score 1):

My Objective-C is a little rusty, but I believe I can help.

`id` in ObjC is quite similar to `AnyObject` in Swift.

So your type could use `id` but then you would need to cast it

You could us the `isKindOfClass` to test which type is returned and then cast it.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id *someType;

if [someType isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]) {

}

if [someType isKindOfClass:[NSError class]) {

}
```