# iPhone app crashing after a quick stop/restart

Tags: iphone, stack-trace, uitabbar

So my app is crashing when the app is stopped and then restarted really fast here's the stack trace:

It looks like the UITabBar is trying to access a view that is null, hence the exc_bad_access. I'm confused as to why it only happens on the restart, also my tabbar is created fully in IB. Any thoughts would be great.

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

0x30183f24 objc_msgSend + 24
1   Inspirational Quotes            0x00009900 0x1000 + 35072

2   UIKit                           0x338c37b4 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 212

3   UIKit                           0x338c36cc -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 32

4   UIKit                           0x338c2d38 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 248

5   UIKit                           0x339cbc44 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 12

6   UIKit                           0x339cc888 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 308

7   CoreFoundation                  0x35eada3c -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20

8   UIKit                           0x3384af18 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 128

9   UIKit                           0x3384ae80 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32

10  UIKit                           0x33ab1ed8 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 416

11  CoreFoundation                  0x35eada3c -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20

12  UIKit                           0x3384af18 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 128

13  UIKit                           0x3384ae80 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32

14  UIKit                           0x3384ae48 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44

15  UIKit                           0x3384aa98 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 528

16  UIKit                           0x3388f338 -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 16

17  UIKit                           0x33aae560 -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 108

18  CoreFoundation                  0x35eada3c -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20

19  UIKit                           0x3384af18 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 128

20  UIKit                           0x3384ae80 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32

21  UIKit                           0x3384ae48 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44

22  UIKit                           0x3384aa98 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 528

23  UIKit                           0x3384b5c4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 452

24  UIKit                           0x3383cea8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 580

25  UIKit                           0x3383c4dc -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 388

26  UIKit                           0x3381fc94 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 444

27  UIKit                           0x3381f3ac _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6816

28  GraphicsServices                0x35262c80 PurpleEventCallback + 1040

29  CoreFoundation                  0x35e9a5c4 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 22

30  CoreFoundation                  0x35e9a582 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158

31  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c82e __CFRunLoopRun + 574

32  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220

33  CoreFoundation                  0x35e8c412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54

34  GraphicsServices                0x35261d1c GSEventRunModal + 188

35  UIKit                           0x33865574 -[UIApplication _run] + 580

36  UIKit                           0x33862550 UIApplicationMain + 964

37  Inspirational Quotes            0x00002b96 0x1000 + 7062

38  Inspirational Quotes            0x00002b0c 0x1000 + 6924

Answer (score 0):

You got the exception `exc_bad_access`, I think your nib file is not connected properly.Connect your tab bar with a tab bar controller.

Comment: In my view I have a TabBarController which contains/ is connected to a tab bar. That tab bar is connected all the appropriate nibs for each tabbaritem... so I don't think this is the issue. but maybe it is?

Comment: 'exc_bad_access' shows for huge memory leakage.But it seems to me, you got exception for showing a tab by-default.

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid from crashing use Exception Handling, here is the following links which may help you.

[throwing an exception in objective-c/cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324284/how-to-throw-an-exception-in-objective-c-cocoa/324745#324745)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocExceptionHandling.html

Comment: If I avoid the crash with an exception will the app still be usable afterwards? Or will the gui freeze up?

Comment: @Msencenb GUI will not freeze after using Exception Handling, only that portion or method will skip where your application trying to access NULL value.