# Why @throw in Objective-C is an expensive operation?

Tags: objective-c

I heard the notion of @throw is expensive in Objective-C, what is the reason behind it? Is `throw` in Java also expensive too?

Comment: Start with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/324805/581190) to learn more.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: The link from @robertvojta is an excellent starting point. Exceptions in Objective-C are really that: exceptions. I'd bet many programmers don't use them much if at all. As they are designed to catch programming errors, there are often easier constructs like NSAssert to get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

"Exceptions in Objective C are implemented using the C primitive: 
longjmp(). Objective-C is not C++. You may have many layers of method 
call between the code that raises the exception and the method that 
catches it. It is very easy to write a memory leak."

http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.sys.mac.programmer.help/2007-08/msg00020.html

Also...

"A little more information.

C++ exceptions and, under the modern ABI, Objective-C exceptions are
extremely cheap to set up (@try), but expensive to @throw and @catch.

When the @throw happens, there is a heavy cost to generating the bits
necessary to properly unwind the stack.

Unfortunately, the AppKit has an issue where it causes the unwind info
to be generated as a normal part of its operation (without throwing an
exception).

Thus, certain AppKit operations in 64 bit can be quite slow at this
time.

b.bum"

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/217947-cocoa-application-running-very-slow-under-64-bit.html

Answer (score 3):

Modern Objective-C uses C++ exceptions.  While [there is a cost associated with throwing a C++ exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835817/are-exceptions-in-c-really-slow), it's hardly prohibitive in most cases.

The reason exceptions are not used with Objective-C is because of memory management.

Languages like Java and C++ have built-in mechanisms for dealing with memory management when an exception is thrown.  Objective-C does not (unless you wrap everything in C++ stack objects).

Instead, when you `throw` in Objective-C, all strong references inside of the enclosing `try` block will simply leak.  There are ways to code around that, but it's very complicated and error prone and is therefore unwise in practice.