# Raising an error while object initialisation for wrong param value Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, error-handling, initialization

Forgive me as it is quite basic, but I want to confirm what's the best way out there.
I am creating an instance using "initWith" type of approach, using the designated initializer -

`(instancetype)initSignUpParamsWithType:....`

In the implementation of the designated initializer it goes something like:

```
   self = [super init];
        if (self) {

            if (type != requiredType) {
                // what needs to be done in this case for raising a proper error? 
               return nil;
            }
            self.type = type;
            self.username = username;
            self.password = password;
```

Now, in the above method if some param value is **NOT** what the object seeks, I want to raise an error during the initialization. In Java, we can throw an exception in such cases.

I know we can throw an exception in Objective-C too, but it is not encouraged for such kind of errors. As can be seen discussed here:
[throwing an exception in objective-c/cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324284/throwing-an-exception-in-objective-c-cocoa)

Can someone please guide me to the best practice around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal it to deal with silly programming errors that will easily be found during testing, then the simplest solution is to use `NSAssert`.

For example:

```
NSAssert(type == requiredType, @"Bad programmer passed in incorrect type of %d", type);
```

Use this in place of your `if` statement. Better yet, make this the first line of the `initSignUp...` method.

If the method is called with the wrong type, the app will crash showing the message provided in the `NSAssert` call.

Another option, used by many of Apple's APIs is to throw an `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try and update if that solves the problem.

Comment: That solves it, It seems to behave similar to the functionality implemented in its Java counterpart.